# Собственный список на Java

Tags: java

Надо считать из двух файлов два списка. И создать третий список, который содержит элементы, которые есть в первом, но нет во втором и которые есть во втором, но нет в первом списке. Вот мой код, правда я пока только пыталась вывести на консоль эти элементы,  а не в список вставить. Не могу понять, в чем ошибка.

```
public class Element {
    public int value;
    public Element next;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Element head1 = null, head2 = null, temp1 = null, temp2 = null;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C://Users//1//Desktop//12w.txt"));
    if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        head1 = new Element(); //голова списка
        int m = sc.nextInt();
        head1.value = m; // вставляю первый элемент в голову
        temp1 = head1; // указатель, который на данный момент указывает на голову
        while (sc.hasNextInt()) { // заполняю список
            m = sc.nextInt();
            temp1.next = new Element();
            temp1 = temp1.next; // перемещаю на следующее место
            temp1.value = m;
        }
    }

    sc = new Scanner(new File("C://Users//1//Desktop//12.txt")); // аналогично заполняю второй список
    if (sc.hasNextInt()) {

        head2 = new Element();
        int m = sc.nextInt();
        head2.value = m;
        temp2 = head2;
        while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            m = sc.nextInt();
            temp2.next = new Element();
            temp2 = temp2.next;
            temp2.value = m;
        }
    }

    int s;
    int m1;
    int m2;
    temp1 = head1; //cсылаю указатель на голову
    while (temp1.next != null) {
        m1 = temp1.value; // делаю до тех пор пока указатель не ссылается на null

        s = 1;
        while (temp2.next != null) {
            m2 = temp2.value; // аналогично

            if (m1 == m2) {
                s = 0;
                break; // если два элемента при первом проходе равны
            }
            temp2 = temp2.next; // ссылаю указатель на след элемент
        }
        temp1 = temp1.next;
        if (s == 1) {
            System.out.println(temp1.value);
        }
        temp2 = head2; // указатель ссылаю на голову
    }
}
```

Comment: а в чем ошибка?)

Comment: допустим у меня два списка 
1 3 5 7 9 11
1 2 3 5 7 9
Ожидаемый результат 2 11
Текущий результат 3 5 7 9 11

Comment: Тут я не вижу построения 3-го списка. @Ksenia, отформатируйте нормально код и добавьте комментарии более "верхнего" уровня перед блоками кода. 

Типа:

// строим из файла первый список.

// добавим в результат элементы первого списка, которых нет во втором

и т.п.

Comment: вся задача решается 3мя массивами и одним методом =)

Comment: @Gorets, совершенно очевидно, что автору нужно **не найти** разность между объединением и пересечением 2-х множеств, а освоить технику работы с односвязными  списками.

Стремление же не использовать стандартные коллекции и методы можно только приветствовать.

Comment: смотря на этот "код" сложно, что-то утверждать

Comment: Главное желание. Человек **учится**. 

Напишет пару сотен программок (по парочке в день), почитает чужой **нормальный** код и свой код станет совсем другим.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

попробуй так:

1. вычитывай свои списки (как тебе удобно, тут я тебе не посоветю, т.к.
       не вижу формат файлов и т.п.)
2. Затем в класс Element добавляешь метод

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object object) {
     if (object != null) {
       if(this.value!= null && ((Element)object).getValue() != null){
          return this.value.equals(((Element)object).getValue());
       }
     }
     return false;
   }
3. Затем пользуешься методом contains() у списка чтобы узнать содержится ли элемент первого списка в списке номер 2. Если не содержится, добавляем в список 3, если содержится - удаляем из списка 2. Пример:

   for(Element element : elements1){
     if(!elements2.contains(element)){
       elements3.add(element);
     } else {
       elements2.remove(element);
     }
   }

после этого в списке 2 останутся те элементы, которые не содержаться в списке 1. просто добавляем их в список 3:

elements3.addAll(elements2);

все. Пробуй, удачи :)

p.s. сорри, но код не форматируется, извиняйте что в одну строку все

Comment: @piratewater, Вы вопрос-то прочитали ? Код посмотрели ?

@Ksenia **сама** пытается реализовать  **Собственный список на Java** (это заголовок вопроса).

Вы же советуете ей воспользоваться **стандартными** Java списками.

Comment: @avp, зачем изобретать велосипед??? И самое интересное, что этот ответ был принят, по логике это именно то, что @Ksenia хотела

Comment: Заметил. 

Может быть девушка приняла ответ от безысходности ? Судя по коду в вопросе она хотела сделать **сама**.

По поводу "велосипедов". Если не пытаться их изобретать, хакером (в первоначальном  значении этого термина) не станешь.

Comment: может-не может... Это уже философия какая-то. От безысходности можно было принять ваш ответ :). Я предлагаю только эффективный код, одно из правил написания которого, как я уже говорил - Do it simple. 
А по поводу "велосипедов" - пока вы будете изобретать очередной велосипед, пытаясь стать хакером - ваши "конкуренты" шагнут далеко вперед в развитии. Хакером становятся не изобретая велосипеды, а находя что-то новое (это мое мнение). Но опять же - это философия. А мы рассматриваем вопрос по программированию, который уже давно решен. Так что давайте не будем наезжать с предположениями

Comment: Do it simple. Тогда уж изначальное KISS. Если быть последовательным, то:

1) Для списков int value новый class Element не нужен. Достаточно в LinkedList заносить числа методом .add()

2) Задача решается с одним временным списком (это чтобы не менять исходные) методами .addALL() и .removeALL() класса LinkedList без всяких циклов (7 строчек, включая удаление временного списка и печать результата).

--

Реализацию предоставим TC.

Comment: Согласен! Я отталкивался от того, что у нас исходный список все таки состоит из объектов Element (или любых других). В который может входить не только int значение. И необходимо сравнить именно не приметивные ОБЪЕКТЫ (по определенному полю, или нескольким полям). То есть я попытался рассказать про использование метода contains() и реализацию метода equals() для сложных объектов.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы правильно решать такие задачи, ты должна четко представлять алгоритм действий. Для этого лучше сесть и на бумажке написать все по пунктам:

1. считываем данные с 2-х файлов
2. циклом проверяем элементы 1 списка во 2-м
3. так же элементы 2ого в 1-м
4. если условие (contain()) - `false` - записываем элемент в новый массив

Comment: я понимаю свой алгоритм, но не могу понять в какой момент времени он не правильно начинает работать

Comment: я это к тому, что такой код сложно поддерживать и понимать, у тебя там черт ногу сломит, куча переменных, кто-то с кем-то сравнивается, кто-то зануляется. Вряд ли кто-то тебе сможет тут помочь =)

Comment: попыталась написать комментарии, чтобы было чуть-чуть понятен мой код

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я вижу при первом же цикле

```
while(temp1.next!=null){ ...
    while(temp2.next!=null)
```

temp2.next будет null, т.к. temp2 как указывал на хвост второго списка, так и остался.